# I'd like to learn PDE via videos.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'd love to learn Partial differential equations by watching videos. Are there any free videos available?
I haven't been able to find a good one. I'm kinda new to PDE. I want that teachers explain things as easily as they can so that even a teenager could understand.

Or, I'd be happy if you recommend online lectures which require some money.

Comment: [MIT opencourseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/) has [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvL88xqYSak&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63oTpyxCMLKt_JmB0WtSZfG) on differential equations (see videos 51-56) and just about everything else you might encounter in an undergraduate course.

Comment: @mattos I’ve already watched that lecture.  They are almost all about ODE. MIT doesn’t have any open courses about PDE.

Comment: @mattos help me bro.